# Add Angular 6 bindings and validations to JSP pages coming as response from server

Tags: angular, validation, jsp, data-binding, dynamic-forms

In my ANGULAR 6 project I have a requirement of dynamic forms to be implemented. 
So as of now the jsp form page with all the required fields will coming as response from server.

But how can I access this jsp page and make it as a component and add bindings and validations to each fields of the jsp form?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use reactive forms which is used mostly for dynamic forms ,http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.com/2018/09/angular-reactive-forms.html

Comment: @HameedSyed , If we are adding dynamic forms using reactive forms, I should get what all fields need to be added in form as a json object from server. But I don't want that approach. In my case the whole jsp/html with fields required will coming as response and I need to do the validation and bindings to each fields in the form